# Expose types in a referenced dll to another projects

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, reference

So, I have a DataModel project. I have certain domain models that are already inside a third party library. so I add the third party reference in my DataModel.

Not I want my other projects have access to internal third party Dll Types by adding a reference to my DataModel Project. I don't want to add the third party library to all my projects..

in another words I want to have

```
DataModel.Type thirdPartyType = new DataModel.Type
```

I tried creating a class in my DataModel project that inherits from the third party type since it has access to it. But it's not usable in another projects since they don't have access to it's parent.

How should I achieve that ?

Comment: You can't reference any types in the 3rd party library without a reference to it. You should encapsulate the operations that need to access those types within the DataModel project.

Comment: How can I do that ? Let's say have a "Person" type in the third party. I want to make it available to another project without referencing it directly ...

Comment: You can't do that, and if you need to then just reference the library. Encapsulation is one of the tenets of OOP, you can do operations on Person within DataModel but you can't let external callers know about Person.